# Displaying Unique First Item From Comma Separated Strings Stored In MYSQL Database

Tags: php, unique, categories

```
<ul class="p-b-54">
    <li class="p-t-4">
        <a href="#" class="s-text13 active1">
        All
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php 
    $category_query_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `Category` FROM `laptops`  ORDER BY `Id` DESC LIMIT 100 ";
    $run_query_category = mysqli_query($con,$category_query_sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query_category) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query_category)){
            $product_Category = $row["Category"];                
    ?>

    <li class="p-b-9">
        <a href="#" class="s-text7">
        <?php 
        $prod_Cat = explode(", ", $product_Category);
        echo $prod_Cat[0]; 
        ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php 
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

This is how they are saved in the database

```
Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Computers & Tablets, Laptops, Traditional Laptops
Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Computers & Tablets
Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Computers & Tablets, Laptops, 2 in 1 Laptops
Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Computers & Tablets, Tablets
Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Monitors
Electronics, Accessories & Supplies, Audio & Video Accessories, TV Accessories & Parts, TV Ceiling & Wall Mounts
Electronics, Accessories & Supplies, Audio & Video Accessories
Electronics, Camera & Photo, Digital Cameras, DSLR Cameras
Electronics, Television & Video, Televisions
Electronics, PC Gaming, Gaming Computers
Gaming Monitors
Gaming Laptops
```

This is what am expecting

```
Electronics
Gaming Monitors
Gaming Laptops
```

I want to get rid of all duplicate electronics

So far my output is

```
Electronics
Electronics
Electronics
Electronics
Electronics
Electronics
Electronics
Electronics
Electronics
Electronics
Gaming Monitors
Gaming Laptops
```

I have a list of categories stored in mysql database with comma separated words. 
I have managed to display the first word form each string. Though my intentions are getting unique categories after extracting the first words. But as you can see am getting all duplicate content. How do i get rid of them?

IF YOU WANT TO CREATE THE TABLE THIS IS THE SQL QUERY

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `gaminglaptops`
--

CREATE TABLE `gaminglaptops` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Category` text NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `gaminglaptops`
--

INSERT INTO `gaminglaptops` (`Category`) VALUES
('Gaming Laptops'),
('Electronics, PC Gaming, Gaming Computers'),
('Gaming Monitors'),
('Electronics, Television & Video, Televisions'),
('Electronics, Camera & Photo, Digital Cameras, DSLR Cameras'),
('Electronics, Accessories & Supplies, Audio & Video Accessories, TV Accessories & Parts, TV Ceiling & Wall Mounts'),
('Electronics, Accessories & Supplies, Audio & Video Accessories'),
('Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Monitors'),
('Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Computers & Tablets, Tablets'),
('Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Computers & Tablets, Laptops, 2 in 1 Laptops'),
('Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Computers & Tablets'),
('Electronics, Computers & Accessories, Computers & Tablets, Laptops, Traditional Laptops');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `gaminglaptops`
--
ALTER TABLE `gaminglaptops`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
```

Comment: @Samir I know but i don't want to mess with the query because i will also use it for sub categories. I want to pull everything then manipulate it with php.

Comment: If you can provide how sub categories are shown, may be I can help with that too.

Comment: just nested ul li that drops down after you click the main category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query a bit to return unique results.

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) to extract 1st value,

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('Electronics, PC Gaming, Gaming Computers', ',', 1)
```

will return `Electronics`.

Then do a distinct on your query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Category`, ',', 1)) AS Cat
FROM `laptops`
ORDER BY `Id`
DESC LIMIT 100
```

Now the query will return unique results with one value only. So, you can eliminate the need to explode the results in your loop. Optimized your snippet below,

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query_category)) {
?>
<li class="p-b-9">
    <a href="#" class="s-text7"><?php echo $row["Cat"]; ?></a>
</li>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: What if my first word looks like this - Arts, Crafts & Sewing

Comment: If there is a comma in your term as well as comma is used as as separator, then there is no way to identify string delimiter. Consider changing the separator to any uncommon character like `|` or something unique that doesn't appear in your actual text.

Answer (score 0):

try with `continue` statement

```
<ul class="p-b-54">
    <li class="p-t-4">
        <a href="#" class="s-text13 active1">
        All
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php 
    $cat_name = "";
    $category_query_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `Category` FROM `laptops`  ORDER BY `Id` DESC LIMIT 100 ";
    $run_query_category = mysqli_query($con,$category_query_sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query_category) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query_category)){
            $product_Category = $row["Category"];                
    ?>

    <li class="p-b-9">
        <a href="#" class="s-text7">
        <?php 
        $prod_Cat = explode(", ", $product_Category);
        if($cat_name == $prod_Cat[0]){
            continue;
        }else{
            $catname = $prod_Cat[0];
        }
        echo $catname;
        ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php 
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its Working but its outputing a lot of empty spaces between <li>.

Comment: so use `echo $catname` inside else part its working.

Comment: if($cat_name == $prod_Cat[0]){
            continue;
        }else{
            $cat_name = $prod_Cat[0];
            echo $cat_name;
        } Produces the same result

Comment: and remove `echo $catname` in last?

Comment: cutting and pasting doesnt work  ?>

      <li class="p-b-9">
      <a href="#" class="s-text7">
       <?php 
       $prod_Cat = explode(", ", $product_Category);
 if($cat_name == $prod_Cat[0]){
            continue;
        }else{
            $cat_name = $prod_Cat[0];
            echo $cat_name;
        }
        
       
       ?>
      </a>
     </li>
<?php 
  }
 }

 ?>

Comment: Your answer doesn't work did you test it on your side ?

Comment: without proper data how can i test

Comment: I have added the sql query the rest is just Unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approached would probably be to create an empty array (such as $uniqueElements), iterate each of your elements in a for-loop and push each unique item into your empty array by checking the content with in_array($element, $uniqueElements).

Answer (score 0):

You should save all your first-words in an array instantiated at the start like

```
$first_categories = [];
```

And then, for the sake of simplicity, in each iteration you could just append the value to the array like

```
$first_categories[] = $prod_Cat[0];
```

And get a new array with only the unique values

```
$unique_first_categories = array_unique($first_categories);
```

Comment: Your answer is not working also i had tried array unique before       <li class="p-b-9">
      <a href="#" class="s-text7">
       <?php 
       $prod_Cat = explode(", ", $product_Category);
                             
                             $first_categories = [];
                             $first_categories[] = $prod_Cat[0];
                             $unique_first_categories = array_unique($first_categories);

                             echo $unique_first_categories[0];

       ?>
      </a>
     </li>
<?php

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving it an array and check if exist

```
<ul class="p-b-54">
    <li class="p-t-4">
        <a href="#" class="s-text13 active1">
        All
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php 
        $cat_name = "";
        $allCat = array();
        $category_query_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `Category` FROM `laptops`  ORDER BY `Id` DESC LIMIT 100 ";
        $run_query_category = mysqli_query($con,$category_query_sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query_category) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query_category)){
                $product_Category = $row["Category"];
                $prod_Cat = explode(", ", $product_Category);

                if(!in_array($prod_Cat[0], $allCats) { // if not yet exist in array
                     // push to allCats (unique)
                     array_push($allCats, $prodCat[0]);
                    // display
                    ?>

                    <li class="p-b-9">
                        <a href="#" class="s-text7">
                        <?php 
                            echo end($allCats); // last item pushed
                        ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php 
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Working But Producing empty li       <li class="p-b-9">
      <a href="#" class="s-text7">
             </a>
     </li>

      <li class="p-b-9">
      <a href="#" class="s-text7">
       Gaming Monitors      </a>
     </li>

      <li class="p-b-9">
      <a href="#" class="s-text7">
       Gaming Laptops      </a>

Comment: This is what i exactly did       <li class="p-b-9">
      <a href="#" class="s-text7">
       <?php 
       $prod_Cat = explode(", ", $product_Category);
                            
                                 if(!in_array($prod_Cat[0], $allCats)) { 
                   
                     array_push($allCats, $prod_Cat[0]);
                  
                     if ($prod_Cat[0] != "") {
                      # code...
                      echo $prod_Cat[0];
                     }
                             }

       ?>
      </a>
     </li>
<?php 
  }
 }

 ?>

Answer (score 0):

my answer updated

```
<li class="p-b-9">
    <a href="#" class="s-text7">
    <?
        echo end($allCats); // last item 
    ?>
    </a>
</li>
```